# Reverse shell over SSL socket

Tags: c, sockets, ssl

I'm working on my own reverse shell written in C from scratch, mostly for learning purposes. [Here](https://github.com/Chiggins/reverse_shell/blob/master/reverse_shell.c) is my plain reverse shell code, working totally fine and as expected. Now. to make it a bit more secure, I'd like to add SSL on top of it. Now [here](https://github.com/Chiggins/reverse_shell/blob/ssl-shell/reverse_shell.c) is my SSL code. That all works and will print back my text back to my `ncat -lvvp 5000 --ssl` listener. But if I uncomment the `execl` line and comment the `ssl_write` line, I make my SSL socket connection but if I type in any commands, I get nothing in return and then the socket closes.

I'm wondering if `execl` isn't running over SSL and that's what I'm not getting anything back and the socket closing?

Anything looking interesting that I could fix here? Thanks!

Comment: it's been too long since I've used fork/exec to remember for sure, but I _thought_ that exec will close any file descriptors from your original program (and sockets are file descriptors); if you change it so you do a fork and then exec in the child (and just wait for the chilld to finish in the parent), does that make things work better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up achieving what I wanted through a different mean. Instead of running `excel` to open `/bin/sh` and running commands through that, I instead just used `popen()` to run the command and return the value. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

The following code:

```
dup2(c->socket, 0);
dup2(c->socket, 1);
dup2(c->socket, 2);
```

is not right. Using OpenSSL to initiate a TLS connection over this socket doesn't automatically convert all subsequent output to the socket to TLS - you have to keep on using OpenSSL to perform that translation. Duping that socket over standard input, output, and error makes the shell start trying to use that socket for *unencrypted* I/O; because its output isn't valid TLS data, this is causing your ncat to get confused and exit.

You'll need to keep your parent process running to translate the shell's input and output to TLS. This will probably involve some sort of `select()` loop to "pump" input and output between the socket and the shell subprocess.

Comment: What if I have something like two sockets... One is the external one with SSL, and then that connects to a "middle man" one that will read/write from the execl?

Comment: Correct, that's exactly what I'm describing in my second paragraph. It doesn't need to be a socket, though; a pipe is sufficient.

Comment: I'll admit, pretty new at this. Do you know of any tutorials/references that I could look into to connecting a socket to a pipe so I can accomplish this?